# How to post, create events and invite friends on Facebook using Ruby? May be Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, facebook

Is there any interface or a gem that is useful for a Ruby/Ruby on Rails developer for:

1. Posting posts;
2. Sending invatation to friends;
3. Create events on Facebook

Answer (score 1):

1 minute of Googling produces:

https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker

Comment: True, however the key point is to find the right solution there are many libraries out there and asking people with experience like you are would be beneficial thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out facebooker or rFacebook but facebooker seems to be much more actively maintained.

Facebooker- https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker

rFacebook- http://rfacebook.rubyforge.org/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Currently i use the [fbgraph](https://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph) gem 
It was easy to install and there are some examples on github like:

https://github.com/nov/fb_graph_sample